# How to use Angular Js with Google Maps To render a people list when clicking on a marker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Angular JS v1 and I need to render a list of people when I click on a marker on a map , I need the marker to have number on it and this number is an indicator for the number of people from this country and when I click this marker on the map , a list with the same number as the marker appears below

Similar to this website
http://www.travelgirls.com/trips/

Comment: Are you using https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ or something different?

Comment: yes I used this library and I just rendered the map and some markers

Comment: but if there are some better options please advice @kabaehr

Comment: No I also use this one

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i hope it helps you. If not i will improve this answer later on (i have not so much time now)

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" options="markerOptions" events="markerEvents" icon="'icon'"></ui-gmap-markers>
    <ui-gmap-window coords="model.selectedMarker" show="model.selectedMarker.show" templateUrl="'/app/controls/gMapsControl/mapInfoWindow.html'" templateParameter="model.selectedMarker" closeClick="model.closeInfoWindow(model)" isIconVisibleOnClick="false"></ui-gmap-window>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

/app/controls/gMapsControl/mapInfoWindow.html':

```
<div>
    <h5>{{parameter.title}}</h5>
    <h6>Affected Devices</h6>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="device in parameter.control">
            <span class="clickable-device" ui-sref="main.details({id: device.id})">{{device.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This InfoWindow is showing a list of devices on marker click. Also it is possible to route to another site when selecting a device from the rendered list.

`parameter` is the `selectedMarker` passed over `templateParameter` and `parameter.control` therefore is the device list. This devicelist is attached to every marker model. Yeah... maybe not the greatest solution but it was fine for our use case

Comment: I am sorry but this is supposed to do the same like what I am referring to on the link ?
https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Comment: I don´t understand your question. But i just saw that you want to put the data below the map not inside a map info window. This would look different.

Comment: I would like to put a label on the marker holding the number of people of a country and when i click on that marker those people shows from the all list of people